# Delphi XE2 cannot find ComObj.dcu where did it go?

Tags: delphi, com, delphi-xe2

I'm trying to install the jvcl from source, but I'm getting an error in 
line #1267 of unit JvInterpreter;

```
uses
  TypInfo,
  {$IFDEF JvInterpreter_OLEAUTO}
  OleConst, ActiveX, ComObj,
```

So I removed `ComObj` from the uses and waited for the error further down the line:

There's an error concerning `EOLEError`, which is part of OleAuto I added that and hoped for the best, but....

I get an error on this line #1799:

```
DispatchInvoke(IDispatch(Dispatch), CallDesc, PDispIDList(@DispIDs[0]), ParamTypes, Result);
```

So the question is: what happened to `ComObj` and what unit do I need for `DispatchInvoke` in XE2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to change the `uses` to use a fully qualified name:

```
uses
  TypInfo,
  {$IFDEF JvInterpreter_OLEAUTO}
  OleConst, ActiveX, 
  {$IFDEF VER230} system.win.ComObj, {$ELSE} ComObj, {$ENDIF}
```

Now it compiles without error.
See: [What is the compiler version for Delphi 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369191/what-is-the-compiler-version-for-delphi-2010)
For a list of compiler defines.

Comment: Alternatively, you can add "System.Win" to the project's list of available Unit Scope Names, then you do not have to change the original code at all.

Answer (score 2):

Simply add system.win i.e. instead of comobj use system.win.comobj