# SysUtils.LongDayNames undeclared identifier

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

I am very much new to delphi and i tried the following code

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  myDate : TDateTime;
  day    : string;

begin
  myDate := EncodeDate(2002, 12, 31);

  day := LongDayNames[DayOfWeek(myDate)];

  ShowMessage('Christmas day 2002 is on a '+day);
end;
```

I have declared `System.SysUtils` in `Uses` section but still i am getting the error Undeclared identifier.

I am using Delphi XE3 17.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In XE2 LongDayNames moved to TFormatSettings.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.SysUtils.TFormatSettings.

So you could use:

```
day := FormatSettings.LongDayNames[DayOfWeek(myDate)];
```

FormatSettings is a not threadsafe global variable.

How to use it a intended you can see [here](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TFormatSettings)

Comment: my code is scattered with `{$IFDEF DELPHI15}` directives. where is DELPHI15 defined and what is the value for it?

Comment: AFAIK only VERxxx is official http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369191/what-is-the-compiler-version-for-delphi-2010,  here I can find an example for a implementaion with DELPHI15, but might differ from INC to INC http://trac.xananews.techtips.com.br/browser/trunk/components/LowLevel/Source/CompVers.inc

Comment: Delphi Jedi also uses DELPHIxx defines so you could use that include file