# Delphi version specific compilation related to graphics and AnsiStrings units

Tags: delphi, conditional-compilation, versioninfo

I have one unit which I want to be compiled under any Delphi version from let's say Delphi 2006.

It has next code which have problems compiling:

```
uses
  graphics; // for previous versions can not be compiled on Delphi XE

uses
  vcl.graphics; // compiled on Delphi XE but can not compile on previous version
```

And functions StrLen, StrCopy produce "deprecated. moved to AnsiString" warning.

Question is: How to sort it all out? From which compiler version graphics become vcl.graphics, and StrLen moved to AnsiStrings? To create next code:

```
uses
  {$if CompilerVersion < ??}graphics{$ifelse}vcl.graphics{$ifend};
```

Comment: Which question do you want us to answer? The one relating to namespaces, or the one relating to deprecated functions? It's one question at a time. They are probably both duplicates. But we can't close as a duplicate of two questions. You are going to have your work cut out making code work with ANSI and Unicode Delphi. Takes a degree of skill. How well do you understand that issue?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1369191/62576 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/23704097/62576 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8460037/62576

Answer (score 2):

The `Graphics` unit was renamed to `Vcl.Graphics` in XE2, when [Unit Scope Names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Unit_Scope_Names) were first introduced.

[What's New in Delphi and C++Builder XE2](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE2)

> [Important New Requirement: Unit Scope Names for VCL-FMX-RTL](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Unit_Scope_Names)
>
> Important: VCL-FMX-RTL units now use a dotted-prefix naming convention, such as `System.Types` and `Vcl.Styles`. If you have existing code that uses qualified identifiers (such as `Types.IStream`), code changes may be required in order to compile.

You do not need to use an `{$IF}` statement to write cross-version VCL code.  Your `uses` clause can continue to use the `Graphics` unit name by itself:

```
uses
  Graphics;
```

Just make sure that **Vcl** is included in the **Unit scope names** list in the Project Options of XE2+ projects (which it should be by default).

This is documented (in fact, the documentation even uses the `Graphics` unit as an example):

[Delphi Compiler Project Options | Delphi Compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Delphi_Compiler)

> Specifies the [unit scope names](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Unit_Scope_Names) (prefixes) for Delphi dotted namespaces, to allow you to use partially qualified names in your code and in your `uses` clause or `#include`.
>
> There are two ways to add a unit scope name for a Delphi unit:
>
> - Specify the fully unit-scoped name in your uses clause. For example:
>
>   ```
>   uses Vcl.Graphics;
>   ```
> - Add the unit scope name (`Vcl`) to the **Unit scope names** field. Then the unit scope name `Vcl` is automatically applied to unit names that belong to that unit scope, and you can simply specify:
>
>   ```
>   uses Graphics;
>   ```
>
> The Ellipsis pop-up button opens an  [dialog box](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Ordered_list_dialog_box) for selecting and adding unit scope names, as described in [Common Items on Project Options Pages](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Common_Items_on_Project_Options_Pages) and [Ordered list dialog box](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE2/en/Ordered_list_dialog_box)

If you choose to use an `{$IF}` statement, the correct syntax is:

```
uses
  {$IF RTLVersion >= 23}Vcl.{$IFEND}Graphics;
```

Or:

```
uses
  {$IF RTLVersion >= 23}Vcl.Graphics{$ELSE}Graphics{$IFEND};
```

As for the `PAnsiChar` versions of `SysUtils.StrLen()` and `SysUtils.StrCopy()`, they were deprecated and moved to the `System.AnsiStrings` unit in XE4 (`RTLVersion=25.0`).  For example:

```
uses
  ...
  {$IF RTLVersion >= 25}, AnsiStrings{$IFEND}
  ;

var
  Src, Dest: PAnsiChar;
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Src := ...;
  Len := {$IF RTLVersion >= 25}AnsiStrings.{$IFEND}StrLen(Src);
  GetMem(Dest, Len * SizeOf(AnsiChar));
  {$IF RTLVersion >= 25}AnsiStrings.{$IFEND}StrCopy(Dest, Src);
  ...
end;
```

Lastly, note that `{$IF}` was introduced in Delphi 6, so if you need to support Delphi 5 or earlier, you have to wrap `{$IF}` statements in an `{$IFDEF CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS}` block.

Comment: [pre]Thanks. This is what I was looking for.

uses
  {$IF RTLVersion >= 23}Vcl.Graphics{$ELSE}Graphics{$IFEND};

And

uses
  ...
  {$IF RTLVersion >= 25}, AnsiStrings{$IFEND}

This unit will be used by other people, and I want to avoid questions like "why I can not compile this" because VCL is not in included in scope names (and in dll unit it is not by default).
[/pre]

Comment: @Mike There is documentation for this you know

Answer (score -1):

You could also use unit aliases to set things up... it's a time-travel-to-the-past future compatible way if you really need it, but will be a lot of work to setup per unit for example:

A time-travel-to-the-post future compatible example of a unit alias:
VCL.Graphics=Graphics