# Conditionally compiling only parts of Delphi code in C++Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, conditional-compilation

Is there a way to conditionally compile part of Delphi code in Delphi only (but not in C++Builder)?

Rationale:

OmniThreadLibrary contains overloaded properties in type `TOmniValue`.

```
property AsArrayItem[idx: integer]: TOmniValue 
  read GetAsArrayItem write SetAsArrayItem; default;
property AsArrayItem[const name: string]: TOmniValue 
  read GetAsArrayItem write SetAsArrayItem; default;
```

This concept does not translate to C++. (IOW, if you try to compile this code with C++Builder, compilation fails.)

One way to solve the problem is to rename one of the properties and remove the `default` specifier from it.

```
property AsArrayItem[idx: integer]: TOmniValue 
  read GetAsArrayItem write SetAsArrayItem; default;
property AsArrayItemByName[const name: string]: TOmniValue 
  read GetAsArrayItemByName write SetAsArrayItemByName;
```

This way, however, is not backwards compatible and users of the library would have to change the source code that was using the `[string]` version of this default property.

I would like to keep the code backwards compatible and make it work in C++Builder. My idea was to do something like this

```
property AsArrayItem[idx: integer]: TOmniValue 
  read GetAsArrayItem write SetAsArrayItem; default;
{$IF CompilingInDelphi}
property AsArrayItem[const name: string]: TOmniValue 
  read GetAsArrayItem write SetAsArrayItem; default;
{$ELSEIF CompilingInC++Builder}
property AsArrayItemByName[const name: string]: TOmniValue 
  read GetAsArrayItemByName write SetAsArrayItemByName;
{$IFEND}
```

but it looks like there is no useful symbol that could be used for such conditional compilation.

Comment: It looks as if you are out of luck, indeed. I guess you'll have to $DEFINE a symbol manually. There seems to be no way to detect if the Delphi compiler is compiling for Delphi or for C++Builder.

Comment: But perhaps you can $HPPEMIT C++ code (to the .hpp file)  that ignores the faulty declarations.

Comment: Indeed, using an 'external' symbol (something like CppBuilderCompatibleMode) is probably a way to go. @RudyVelthuis, can you add this as an answer?

Comment: $HPPEMIT is better solution, IMO

Comment: Then show me how to do that using $HPPEMIT. I have no idea.

Comment: I tried `$HPPEMIT '#define AsArrayItem AsArrayItemName'}` before the second `AsArrayItem` declaration, and an equivalent #undef after it, but the #define isn't placed there in the .hpp file. It comes much earlier, so it has no effect: the symbol is defined and then immediately undefined again.

Comment: [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2631343/95954) seems to give you a solution: "the BCB define is only set when Delphi is compiling with support for C++Builder (using the -J switches)". I tried it, and it seems to work, indeed.

Comment: So actually this is a duplicate, eh. I'll delete it then. Thanks!

Comment: Don't delete it. I hadn't seen the other solution if I hadn't seen this question. Just leave it as duplicate.